# Must banks in both countries be open for business in order for send a SWIFT/ international money wire?

Tags: international, wire-transfer

If `Bank A` resides in a country where banks are open for business and `Bank B` resides in a country where it is either a weekend or a holiday, could `Bank A` still initiate a SWIFT transaction to send money to `Bank B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can initiate SWIFT payments from Bank A, whenever Bank A is open for business. The transaction takes around 2-5 days for it to complete depending on the currency pair and countries involved. Once you initiate the payment, the Bank A sends it to SWIFT Network which in turn send it to Bank B. Whenever Bank B is open for business it would process the payment.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, where could I have found this information other than asking here or asking a banker? I wasn't successful googling it...

Comment: Truthfully you cannot find out entirely, while this answer is not wrong, it depends a lot on the banks you are dealing with and even the type of transfer - many banks will have it totally automated. 

If you wanted to find out you would have to check the schedule for payments outgoing with Bank A, and payments incoming for Bank B, which should be available on their respective sites.